# cant select the tab drag n sortabke in t he link http://demoqa.com/draggable/ (none of the tabs there)

Tags: java, selenium

I tried using all known element identifier to select the tabs in the drag n drop options in the link but constantly giving error object cant be located . 
can anyone help me.

```
public class DragnDrop {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Auto\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://demoqa.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-item-140']/a")).click();
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
    WebElement know = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tabs']/ul"));
    builder.moveToElement(know, 10, 10 ).click().build().perform();
```

i tried to even use action to click at particular location none worked

Comment: Which bit of the code is failing? Can you post the exact error, and you can also paste the relevant bit of html, or at least clarify exactly which element it is you're having issues with?

Comment: no i need to detect the tab and click it. its not working .. go to the [link](http://demoqa.com/draggable/)  click on the tab http://demoqa.com/draggable/ then click the tab draggable + sortable .. thats the test case my code has all crazy ideas i tried byt failed not focus on it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, if it's the "Draggable + Sortable" tab you're trying to click, the below should allow that:

```
WebElement draggableTab = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-5"));
draggableTab.click();
```

I've tried the above (using C#) and it worked fine.

Comment: I am getting this issue  ' Dec 15, 2016 6:22:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript error: http://demoqa.com/, line 515: ReferenceError: accordion is not defined'

Comment: If it's worked, please upvote/accept the answer so others know, cheers. It would also be better to use a WebDriverWait instead of a Thread.Sleep!

Answer (score 0):

public class DragDrop {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\Browser_Driver\\geckodriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://demoqa.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-item-140']/a")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Draggable + Sortable')]")));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Draggable + Sortable')]")).click();
```

Comment: You can try this one now, Last code I sent you was not dynamically handled. But with Webdriver wait you can click on Draggable+Sortable tab.

Comment: Also, the last code was working on my machine you might face issue due to static wait.
But now you can click on the element you desired.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow community. Please add always some context into your answer so the answer will be easly to unsertand. Avoid always put only code into your answers. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
// code works perfectly for demoqa site
```

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

```
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#sortablebox li"));
    WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.id("draggablebox"));
    WebElement dest1 = list.get(1);
    WebElement dest2 = list.get(4);
    builder.click(source).clickAndHold().moveToElement(dest1).moveByOffset(0, 10).release().build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    builder.click(source).clickAndHold().moveToElement(dest2).moveByOffset(0, 10).release().build().perform();
```

[image: Output of the code]